# Django tests with schema - schema not found

Tags: python, django, amazon-redshift

I'm using Django 1.10.5 in a project setup with `django-cookiecutter`. I have a non-managed model that looks like like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class MyModel(models.Model):
    """Base account model."""
    account_nm = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True,
                                  db_column='customer_nm')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'mylabel'
        db_table = '"stage"."mytable"'
        managed = False if not settings.TESTING else True
```

The managed setting is meant to create my table when I'm testing but under no other circumstances. I'm running my tests with django-pytest simply like `py.test --reuse-db`. My backend is Redshift for this non-managed model with `django-redshift-backend`.

If I run the tests with only `db_table = 'mytable'`, my table is successfully created in the `public` schema in my test database. If I run the tests with the `db_table` as shown above with the schema, I receive an error.

```
E               django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: schema "myschema" does not exist
E               LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "myschema"."mytable" (....
```

I can use this model successfully in my application with the schema specific under normal circumstances. Why am I not able to create the table in my schema while testing?

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because you haven't create `stage` schema in your `test_**` database, whereas `stage` schema is existed in your "development/production" env.

I have run with following steps, and finally successfully run the unit test
(*suppose the database name is `app`*):

1. Dump and copy database `app` to `test_app`.
2. Make sure `stage` schema is created under `test_app`, and `mytable` is created under schema `stage`. (I have temperately turn on `managed` option and run `python migrate`, so that I can let django to create mytable for me)
3. run with django unit test command:

   ```
   python manage.py test --keepdb  # --keepdb is available from django 1.8 and later.
   ```

**test.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import MyModel


class TestMyModel(TestCase):

    def testRetrieve(self):
        self.assertRaises(MyModel.objects.get(pk=1))
```

I haven't try `pytest`, but I think it is mostly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It sure looks like I have created the stage schema in my test database. I'm specifying in my DATABASES setup to use the database named test for my tests.

Comment: @duffn is it possible that the test database is dropped after the test?

Comment: I don't think so. - - reuse-db prevents that.

Comment: @duffn  can u also show the log message for your test?

Comment: The error for the test is `E               django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: schema "myschema" does not exist
E               LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "myschema"."mytable" (....`